# What to do when you are fat and on a long flight - 3 hrs and 9 hrs

Tags: air-travel, health

I am between 200~230 pounds (90~104kg) at 5'6 (167cm) and am fat both at waist and hips.

One of the first things I did from [Is it possible to know which aircraft will fly just from booking flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71048/is-it-possible-to-know-which-aircraft-will-fly-just-from-booking-flights) is to change my seats from K to H in all Qatar Boeing flights so that I could walk up and down the aisle after some period. Are there any other precautions I should take apart from taking water regularly (which I would have to pay for but remain hydrated) is there anything else I should know/take a look at ?

My legs do sleep. Also is there an optimum time interval for taking those short walks which won't annoy the crew/staff.

Also what kind of clothes should I be wearing. I am thinking of either 3/4ths, T-shirt and sport shoes or/and track pants, T-shirts and sport shoes (both without socks as socks smell after time.)

Comment: You can always get water on a plane without paying for it, unless you want  it in a bottle with a fancy label.

Comment: Avoid getting up and taking walks during meal service or when the serving carts are in the galley.

Comment: If you can spend the money, many airlines will sell you an extra "[comfort seat](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/50305/6374)" so you can lift the armrest between 2 seats and have a wider seat. Though you might luck out and be able to purchase a first/business class upgrade for less than the price of a second ticket, though generally the best deals on upgrades aren't available until very close to departure.

Comment: @Johnny not feasible.

Comment: @DJClayworth didn't know that.

Comment: have updated the original question with more sub-questions for clarity.

Comment: By the way, the 787 is notorious for being very, very tight in economy. It's usually best to avoid exit row as the seats are even narrower there.

Comment: @Berwyn so the best seat in economy would be the middle seat where if your luck is not good, you could really be cramped. At least the exit gives the option of having walks without disturbing others, so one can flex their legs.

Comment: @shirish No, I'd say the best seat is an aisle seat that doesn't have fixed armrests. You can always lift up the armrest and lean out into the aisle a little. To clarify, exit row seats are the ones next to the emergency exit.

Comment: Then I am safe, as I have booked all aisle seats, the 'H' series in both 777-300ER and 787-8 from http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71048/is-it-possible-to-know-which-aircraft-will-fly-just-from-booking-flights . I was mistaking the aisle seats with the exit row seats, thank you for pointing those out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Tips:

• Keep hydrated and drink plenty

• Book aisle seats (as you have done)

• Do not keep in one position for too long - go for a little walk every 30 minutes or so, just standing up and stretching can help.

• Don't take walks when meals are being served or the cabin crew have their trolleys out. Be aware that economy can mean that the aisles are rather narrow.

• Wear what you want - but not too many layers or jumpers or anything that you may find uncomfortable. Sports shoes should be fine if they are breathable and not bulky.

• Engage with the passengers around you - so they don't keep staring at you when you get up for a walk or something.
• Eat at different points during the flight - 9 hours is a long time!

Free water is available on most planes as long as you don't want branded water in a bottle.

Answer (score 2):

I am also a fat person and can offer these additional tips:

1. Do not wear anything with a belt; wear loose fitting clothes and baggy cut jeans/pants.
2. Avoid the rows directly behind a bulkhead or next to an exit door. These may look attractive because of the extra legroom, but the seats are narrower than the normal seats because the tray table and video screen are stowed the armrests.
3. I personally avoid sports sneakers; unless I have one that are slightly bigger than my normal size. These are extremely comfortable (especially for long treks in terminals) but I find that they become uncomfortable because you have to wear thicker socks with them, and eventually your feet will swell due to the long time you are sitting.
4. If you are going to take your shoes off, keep your socks on; and keep the laces of the shoes untied. As a big person it is difficult to put on both shoes and socks in economy seating (I usually get up and put on shoes in the isle).

The above tips have served me well on many long flights, hope they help you as well.